# stopping android handler loop

Tags: android

i am using a class which extends Handler class to update my activity UI.
The code is as follows in side main activity,

```
public class RefreshHandler extends Handler {

     public void handleMessage(Message msg) {


      Homeform.this.updateUI();
     }
     public void sleep(long delayMillis) {
      this.removeMessages(0);
         sendMessageDelayed(obtainMessage(0), delayMillis);
     }
 };

 private void updateUI(){
  Log.v(""," I am inside Update UUI=====================");

  refresh();
     mRedrawHandler.sleep(5000);

 }
```

And i had call this method handleMessage() on the object of RefreshHandler as follows

```
mRedrawHandler = new RefreshHandler();

mRedrawHandler.handleMessage(new Message());
```

But here i am facing one problem that it is running after closing my application also .

please solve my problem to stop this handler when close this application.

Thank you..

Comment: I wish I had editing privileges

Comment: @Casebash But I do have edit privileges. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
if(!isFinishing()) {
    sendMessageDelayed(obtainMessage(0), delayMillis);
}
```

i.e. add that if-statement around your sendmessage-line

Answer (score 7):

onDestroy, call remove

mRedrawHandler.removeMessages(0);